# Expiring a boost::steady_timer which is running on a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

My goal is to have multiple threads running utilising one `io_context` and `steady_timer` to perform a bunch of tasks. When the tasks are finished, I want to expire the `steady_timer` and stop all the threads.

I have the following as test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/, boost::asio::steady_timer* t, int* count)
{
    std::cout << "every 2 seconds i count " << (*count)++ << " counts\n";

    t->expires_at(t->expiry() + chrono::seconds(2));
    t->async_wait(boost::bind(print, boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count));
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    io_context my_context;

    steady_timer my_timer(my_context, std::chrono::seconds(2));
    my_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(print, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &my_timer, &count));

    std::thread thread1( [&my_context]() {my_context.run(); } );

    Sleep(20000);

    my_timer.expires_at(my_timer.expiry());                                                         // expire after last action
    my_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(print, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &my_timer, &count));   // wait for it to expire        // doesn't work?
    thread1.join();                                                                                 // doesn't work?

    return 0;
}
```

I have a `steady_timer` handler function named `print`, which has a callback to it's own `steady_timer` object, `t`. I want to create my `steady_timer` object and pass it on to my handler function, then perform some task in the handler function and then expire the `steady_timer` when I'm finished.

However, it seems like expiring my `steady_timer` object doesn't allow my thread to `join()`. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: Why not just use `cancel` method of steady_timer to expire your timer ? Also, you should add some protection when accessing concurrently your timer from 2 threads.

Comment: Because from what I understand from the documentation, `cancel` canels the asynchronous operation, but I want to ensure I finish my last asynchronous operation.

Comment: After doing some more testing, I'm wondering if I can even expire the timer outside of the thread, seeing as inside the thread the timer is always extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in the comment that `cancel` will *cancel* initiated asynchronous operation, but `expires_at` do the same thing (see [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/expires_at/overload2.html), *Any pending asynchronous wait operations will be cancelled*).

Async opertion started in `thread1` by `async_write`, could be cancelled when calling `expires_at` from `main` thread. This logic is just wrong, also if you want to do such thing you should use *mutex* to protect concurrent access to `steady_timer` (shared instance is not thread safe - (see [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html)), *Shared objects: Unsafe.*).

Only safe way to stop infinite chain of `print` function calls is to add to `print` function some stop condition.

You could wrap `steady_timer` in structure with `atomic<bool> finish` member variable. When 20 seconds elapsed, you set this member and check it in `print` function when processing the last handler call. In this way you are confident that all started handler will be called.

```
struct Foo {
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer;
    std::atomic<bool> finish{false};

    template<class Expire>
    Foo(boost::asio::io_context& io, Expire expire) : timer(io, expire) {}
};

void print(const boost::system::error_code& e, Foo* foo, int* count) {
    if (foo->finish)
        return;
    std::cout << "every 2 seconds i count " << (*count)++ << " counts\n";
    foo->timer.expires_at(foo->timer.expiry() + chrono::seconds(2));
    foo->timer.async_wait(boost::bind(print, boost::asio::placeholders::error, foo, count));
}

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    io_context my_context;

    Foo foo(my_context, std::chrono::seconds(2));
    foo.timer.async_wait(boost::bind(print, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &foo, &count));

    std::thread thread1( [&my_context]() {my_context.run(); } );
    Sleep(20000); // 20 s
    foo.finish = true;
    thread1.join();
```

Another solution is to add additional parameter to `print` function, for example named: `bool asTheLastOne`. Every time when you start `async_write` with `print`, you decide if this operation will be the last one.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was indeed doing some more testing myself and realised my logic was just incorrect and would never work. I already implemented some sort of finish flag myself, to ensure the `steady_timer` object doesn't get extended, but I do quite like your idea of a wrapper, so I'll modify this for my needs!